# pytest: Adding fixture in the test file instead of conftest.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-django

I am new to Python and I have a doubt in **pytest**

**test_client.py**

```
# Simple Example tests

import pytest

def test_one():
   assert False == False

def test_two():
   assert True == True

def cleanup():
   # do some cleanup stuff
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
import test_client

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def do_clean_up(request):
    request.addfinalizer(test_client.cleanup)
```

Is it possible to move the fixture defined in **conftest.py** to the **test_client.py** thereby eliminating having **conftest.py**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Why didn't you simply try? ;)

Fixtures are put in `conftest.py` files to be able to use them in multiple test files.